# CLOSE button is ignored whilst in a WHILE LOOP

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a few simple while loops in my program, such as a Countdown program. I also have a bitmap button for close (Doesn't require any code right?). When The countdown is in progress(`while`), everything (All buttons and edits) are ignored/unable to use until the requirements are met with the `loop`.

Is there a way to stop the loop before the requirements are met?

Here's my code:

```
while iCountDown > 0 do
    begin
      application.ProcessMessages;
      dec(iCountDown)
      lblOutput.Caption := IntToStr(iCountDown);
      sleep(1000);
    end;
    ShowMessage ('Countdown has finished!');
```

Thanks.

Comment: `and not Application.Terminated` or throw `EAbort` `OnCloseQuery`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare a private field of your form like this:

```
FCancelLoop: Boolean;
```

Set the variable to `False` before you start your loop. In the `OnClick` event handler of your close button, set `FCancelLoop` to `True`. Check the value of `FCancelLoop` inside the loop and break out of the loop if you find it is `True`.

```
FCancelLoop := False;
while iCountDown > 0 do
begin
  Application.ProcessMessages;
  if FCancelLoop then
    exit; // or perhaps break, but you get the idea
  dec(iCountDown);
  lblOutput.Caption := IntToStr(iCountDown);
  Sleep(1000);
end;
```

However, this code has other problems. It uses the notorious `Application.ProcessMessages` which has a tendency to make your life more complicated than you want it to be. Are your event handlers protected against re-entrancy? And the call to `Sleep` on your main thread blocks that thread and makes it unresponsive. You really don't want that.

A better solution to your problem is to run your countdown loop with a timer.

Answer (score 1):

A different solution could be a thread. Its advantages:

- it does not block the main thread when calling `Sleep`
- `Application.ProcessMessages` is not needed
- it does not interfere with the Close button

When used with `synchronize`, it also can update the Label caption and other UI elements.

The code for the count-down message ('Countdown has finished!') can be executed in the [OnTerminate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Classes.TThread.OnTerminate) event handler - without `synchronize` as it will executed in the *main thread* context.

Comment: Creating a worker thread beacause of making a countdown timer for a single label is really big overkill (think about the synchronisation and resources that you're wasting for such a trivial task). I would never suggest this. [not voting down; just saying]

Comment: @TLama may be right in this case but a thread implemented timer is often a nice solution. It means you don't need to build a state machine.